# Styleable attribute not passed to class

Tags: android, styles

Hi i'm trying to pass an attribute from theme to code but it is not working.

here is my code

styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.custom">
    <item name="skin">custom</item>
</style>
```

manifest:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/Theme.custom" >
...
</application>
```

attrs:

```
<attr name="skin" format="reference|string" />

<declare-styleable name="SkinImageView">
    <attr name="skin" />
    <attr name="resource" />
</declare-styleable>
<declare-styleable name="SkinButton">
    <attr name="skin" />
    <attr name="resource" />
    <attr name="type" format="reference|string"></attr>
    <attr name="skinButtonStyle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="imageButton" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="android:enabled" />
    <attr name="android:clickable" />
</declare-styleable>
```

SkinImageView.java

```
public class SkinImageView extends ImageView {

    protected String skin;

    public SkinImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.SkinImageView);
        String name = array.getString(R.styleable.SkinImageView_resource);
        String sskin = array.getString(R.styleable.SkinImageView_skin);

        array.recycle();

// skin = "NEW:"
    }
}
```

The same code is in SkinButton.java

```
public class SkinButton extends Button {
    private String skin;

    public SkinButton(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SkinButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.skinButtonStyle);
    }

    public SkinButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.SkinButton, defStyle, R.style.SkinButtonDefault);
        setEnabled(array.getBoolean(R.styleable.SkinButton_android_enabled,
                true));
        setClickable(array.getBoolean(R.styleable.SkinButton_android_clickable,
                true));
        String name = array.getString(R.styleable.SkinButton_resource);
        String type = array.getString(R.styleable.SkinButton_type);
        skin = array.getString(R.styleable.SkinButton_skin);
        array.recycle();

// skin = "custom"
    }
}
```

BUT!!!!

Skin button resolves skin as "custom" SkinImageView resolves skin as "NEW:". I've searched there is no "NEW" in entire project

any help?